# Show that the set $E$ has an interval as its image

Tags: real-analysis

Show that a non-empty set $E$ of real numbers is an interval if and only if every continuous real valued function on $E$ has an interval as its image.

Any idea will be gladly appreciate it thanks

Comment: Notice $f:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=0$ is continuous and its domain is an open interval, but the image, the set $\{0\}$, does not contain any interval. So...?

Comment: Perhaps "connected set" is more appropiate here than "interval".

Comment: I think he's talking about closed intervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $E$ is an interval, and $f$ is continuous. Then $f(E)$ is connected, hence an interval.

Suppose every continuous $f:E \to \mathbb{R}$ has an interval as an image. Choose $f(x) = x$, which is continuous. Then $E=f(E)$ is an interval.